# how to set zoom level using css

Tags: html, css, firefox, zooming

I have been developing my webapp with a certain zoom level on firefox that I set initially (using ctrl+wheel). Now when tested on a different PC on firefox, the default 100% seems to be too big. Can I set default using css?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What DA said, zoom is a user controlled setting, but you can size things relative to the zoom, and if users don't use Ctr + - to size, but change the sizing by setting a default font size, you can can over-ride this default setting by setting a font-size in pixels (as opposed to ems, %, etc.).... This however, is generally considered bad practice, since it may make the lettering / sizing illegible and unchangeable to some people, who don't know about Ctr + - and rely on a default font size.

You can adjust sizing relative to the user defaults and zoom setting by setting the font-size in ems or %. This will change the sizing of things relative to the user set sizing.

This enables you to make each page look to another person how it looks to you.... since each person's perception of "small," "medium," and "large" is different.

Answer (score 14):

```html
    <html>    
        <body>
            <div id="sampleDiv" style="width: 100px; background-color: Gray;">
                Zoom Me
            </div>
            <button onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='300%'">Zoom 300%</button>
            <button onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='200%'">Zoom 200%</button>
            <button onclick="sampleDiv.style.zoom='100%'">Zoom 100%</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "invalid property name" in firefox

Answer (score 8):

You can set the zoom using the CSS property `zoom`.  It's an old IE thing which is also supported in Chrome, and Safari.

```
.zoom
{
    zoom: 120%;
}
```

However, this probably shouldn't be used on live sites...

Comment: This still does it xd

Comment: And it doesn't behave the same way (not scaling all elements)

Answer (score 7):

The page zoom is a browser feature, not a CSS setting (well, except for that IE proprietary thing, which is really more useful for fixing IE bugs than anything) so it is a user-controlled variable rather than anything you have control over.